# Is there a way to add spark.driver.extraClassPath through PyCharm?

Tags: apache-spark, pycharm

I'm trying to run a Spark job on my local machine to write some data to a postgres db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this through the [`defaults.conf` configuration file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

This same approach applies regardless of PyCharm, `pyspark`, `spark-shell`, or any other means of invoking Spark.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and now I'm getting other errors. So I'll have to figure out where I'm going wrong.